# How to return an array which is not equal to a specific number in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Number** = 10;

**occupiedBeds** = `[2, 8]`;

I want to return numbers from `1` to `number` not equal to `occupiedBeds`, that is:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
```

My code so far:

```
 const vacantBeds = (number) => {
      const occupiedBeds = patientsData && patientsData.map((patient) => Number(patient.room.slice(-1)[0].bed))
    
      let numArr = [...Array(number).keys()].map((x) => x + 1)
    
      let filtered = numArr.filter((x) => x !== occupiedBeds)
    
      return filtered.map((bed) => (
        <option key={bed} value={bed}>
          {bed}
        </option>
      ))
    }
```

Comment: But x is a number e.g. 3 and occupiedBeds is array [2, 8] How do I compare these two which are not same type.

Comment: ah, sorry, misread the question. So, given `number=10` and `beds=[2,8]`, you want to return `[1, 3,4,5,6,7, 9,10]` - is that correct?

Comment: Yes That is what I want

Comment: Then just use `numArr.filter((x) => !occupiedBeds.includes(x))`

Comment: Yes. Thank you this one solved my problem.  Thanks million times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you

```
  let filtered = numArr.filter( x => !occupiedBeds.includes(x))
```